# best location to deny user agent in nginx for all sites

Tags: nginx

I would like to deny access to a user agent for all my sites without having to repeat the statement below in every server block. Is this possible?

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* ^.*UnWelcomeUserAgentString.*$){
    return 403;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place the statements in a separate file and include them into each of the `server` blocks by using multiple `include` statements. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) for details.